# Why all content inside fields still exists even after the onCreateView method is called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the `A` fragment there are fields and a button that will take the user to the `B` fragment, Let's suppose the user inserts the data inside fields and after that clicked on the button, Now the user in the `B` fragment, Let's suppose the user decided back to the `A` fragment, The `onCreateView` method in the `A` fragment will be called again and will recreate all views but all data that user inserted it in fields still exist.

I know the `onCreateView` method will destroy all views and recreate them again.

This is not a problem for me but rather it is a feature because I want to keep all data in the fields.

For the sake of knowledge only I want to know why all content inside fields still exists even after the `onCreateView` method is called?

Comment: Add code with question.

Answer (score 0):

Views state is saved/restored whenever fragment is recreated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to explain more about fragment lifecycle and what happens on during saving/restoring state. Enhance your answer with links to android official docs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).